# Godot java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service without Chimera impl

Tags: java, android, mobile, game-engine, godot

I'm published a game made with Godot 3.5.2

But Play Console report that there is an error relate to stack call java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service without Chimera impl
Error happen on motorola Motorola G20 Android 11 (SDK 30) 4.096 MB arm64-v8a vi_VN (Vietnamese)

Does anyone face this before? I don't have a Motorola device so how to check it? Android doesn't have any Motorola emulators.

This is the report

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service without Chimera impl
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:2382)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2358)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2341)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2283)
  at nbg.gf (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):11)
  at ndf.h (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):15)
  at sau.a (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):34)
  at sbb.s (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):30)
  at sbb.v (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):125)
  at sbb.i (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):4)
  at sbb.j (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):8)
  at sbb.f (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):21)
  at bagi.b (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):33)
  at bage.a (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):22)
  at com.google.android.gms.chromesync.sync.SyncIntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):129)
  at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):2)
  at agix.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):10)
  at nlg.run (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):70)
  at nlf.run (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):152)
  at djgp.run (:com.google.android.gms@234914031@23.49.14 (150400-590296185):13)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: I've now reported it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/322151208

Feel free to upvote

Comment: I got the same exception in the same circumstances. (Pre-launch report, the same device, just locale is es_ES.) My app does not use Godot, and the issue was found for the first time in a minor update. I suspect this is a chimeric issue.

Answer (score 0):

The same on my side, it sounds to be random anyway as the previous build pass through the bug!

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service without Chimera impl
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:2382)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2358)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2341)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2283)
  at nkh.gg (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):11)
  at nmg.h (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):15)
  at sjv.a (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):34)
  at skc.s (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):30)
  at skc.v (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):125)
  at skc.i (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):4)
  at skc.g (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):6)
  at wun.a (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):19)
  at wun.c (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):1)
  at wua.a (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):366)
  at wxu.f (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):176)
  at bgkg.fj (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):1)
  at bgkr.run (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):100)
  at dkdr.run (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):21)
  at ajsn.c (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):50)
  at ajsn.run (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):76)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at ajyd.run (:com.google.android.gms@235014031@23.50.14 (150400-592568214):8)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).